# Once function returns Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, es6-promise

I want to get some data from my firebase real-time database. It worked once but now returns 'Promise {pending}'

const userId = admin.database()
          .ref(`/dhabba_orders/{userID}`).once('value');

The above code returned the correct value once and now only returns 'Promise {pending}'

```
exports.notificationMake = 
functions.database.ref(`/dhabba_orders/{userId}/status`)
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
  const userId = admin.database()
      .ref(`/dhabba_orders/{userID}`).once('value');
  console.log(userId);  
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: `Hi`,
      body: `Hey`
    }
  };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userId, payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: SOLUTION

```
exports.notificationMake =
functions.database.ref('/dhabba_orders/{user_uid}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    let userId = context.params.user_uid;
    let orderStatus = context.params.order_status;

    Promise.all([userId, orderStatus]).then(others => {
        console.log(userId);  
        console.log(orderStatus);
        const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `Order Accepted!`
        }
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userId, payload);
    return 0;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return 0;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the API documentation, [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) performs a query asynchronously and returns a Promise that you can use to get a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) at the request location in the in the database.  However, you're assuming that it simply returns the value directly.  Instead, you'll need to make use of that Promise in order to get the user ID.  Your function should look more like this:

```
exports.notificationMake =
functions.database.ref('/dhabba_orders/{userId}/status').onWrite((change, context) => {
    admin.database().ref(`/dhabba_orders/{userID}`).once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        const userId = snapshot.data();
        console.log(userId);  
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `Hi`,
                body: `Hey`
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userId, payload);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work. Also requires a catch statement?

Comment: Isn't it because of the backtips in the path? It should be `functions.database.ref('/dhabba_orders/{userId}/status')`.